# Using xpath to accessing the text between non-text children of a node

Tags: xml, xpath

```
 <div>
    foo
    <br />
    bar
    <br />
    baz
 </div>
```

1. What technical terms describe the relationships between bar, baz and the div?
2. How do I use xpath to get bar and baz out of the div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The text nodes `bar` and `baz` are siblings of each other, and children of the `<div>` element.

2 has already been answered correctly.

Answer (score 4):

**First Question :**

bar and baz are text nodes of the element div.

**Second question :**

The following XPath expression.

```
/div/text()[not(contains(., "foo"))]
```

This would work and leave foo out of the retrieved data.

Answer (score 2):

Use node test `text()` to to select text nodes.

```
/div/text()
```

Selects "foo", "bar" and "baz" (and the whitespace) text node children of `<div>`.